# Convert integer interval to "HH:mm:ss" string format

Tags: sql, reporting-services

I'm having an issues with an expression in ssrs. In my table one of the values of a cell is the following expression:

```
=Format(CInt(DateDiff(DateInterval.Second, Fields!JOB_START_TMS.value, Now())), "HH:mm:ss")
```

The issue is that it returns the string "HH:mm:ss"

`Fields!JOB_START_TMS.value` is just a parameter in the select statement of the underlying dataset. Now if i try just `DateDiff(DateInterval.Second, Fields!JOB_START_TMS.value, Now())` it will give me the correct number of seconds, as variable type long.

Any advice on how i can get this difference between `Fields!JOB_START_TMS.value` and the current time in hours:mintues:seconds format?

Thanks.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2481351/how-do-i-convert-an-int-into-hhmmss-using-ssrs-2005?rq=1 , http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13534686/how-to-display-beyond-24-hrs-in-ssrs-2008-in-hhmmss-format?rq=1

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I saw both of those solutions. The links solution has the same issue for me, to string just returns "HH:mm:ss" as a string as well. The second link is not the same problem as mine, his is working only he wants days to work when the minutes/seconds is more than 24 hours.

Comment: Refer .. [example]http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/26d8b4fc-6862-42a0-ac7f-0caa93ba2fde/to-find-ellapse-time-in-ssrs-2008?forum=sqlreportingservices.  In the reference link example  =Datediff("h",Fields!StartDate.value,Fields!EndDate.value) & ":" & Datediff("n",Fields!StartDate.value,Fields!EndDate.value) mod 60 & ":" & Datediff("s",Fields!StartDate.value,Fields!EndDate.value) mod 60

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer from [How do I convert an INT into HH:mm:ss using SSRS 2005](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2481351) that @user2864740 posted with your `DateDiff` in the middle should work:

```
=DateAdd("s", DateDiff("s", Fields!JOB_START_TMS.Value, Now), CDate("00:00")).ToString("HH:mm:ss")
```